# With 3D touch, would it be possible to turn iphone 6s to a simple scale?

Tags: iphone, 3dtouch

Assume 3D touch reports accurate pressure, then one can do the following:

1. Flip the iPhone, support it with 4 fingers under the screen
2. iPhone mark the pressures -> p0[]
3. Put an object on the fingers
4. iPhone mark the new pressures -> p1[]

If we also have finger_area0[] and finger_area1[](while pressing),then:

```
weight_object ~= Sum(finger_area1*p1)-Sum(finger_area0*p0)-weight_iphone
```

And possibly many implementation details (for a simple stupid scale....)

But first, does iPhone 6s provides

1. accurate pressure
2. finger area on press?

Comment: "Hey Siri, do I need to lose weight?"

Answer (score 2):

Ha, I was wondering when the first 6S drug scales apps would appear.

The properties you want are available on `UITouch`:

```
force                 // iOS9/6S
maximumPossibleForce  // iOS9/6S

majorRadius           // iOS8
majorRadiusTolerance  // iOS8
```

You can examine them by overriding the following `UIResponder` methods:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually this is possible, though it has its limits. The iPhone 6s Plus can measure weights between 0 and about 400g. I’ve already written a small App for fun which turns the iPhone 6s into a kitchen scale ;-) I made a small video: https://youtu.be/mzuJOWDI6tE

The „force“ values you get from an UITouch object do have a range from 0 up to 6.66667 and represent a weight between 0 and about 400 g. It looks like the values in this range are very linear, so it’s easy to convert the raw values into a real weight.

But of course this can be only a fun project, because you only get „force“ values when the screen detects a touch, and many objects (plastic, wood etc) can not be detected by the touch screen.

Comment: Could you release the code for this? That would be amazing.